# How to write binary into file in Crystal

Tags: file, binary, crystal-lang

I have an array of UInt32, what is the most efficient way to write it into a binary file in Crystal lang?

By now I am using `IO#write_byte(byte : UInt8)` method, but I believe there should be a way to write bigger chunks, than per 1 byte.

Comment: How are you writing UInt32 with UInt8? Do you mean you are using write_bytes (with an s at the end)?

Comment: Currently I am keeping array of UInt8 and writing UInt8. But I guess it will be better to keep array of UInt32 and use it for writing as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can directly write a `Slice(UInt8)` to any IO, which should be faster than iterating each item and writing each bytes one by one.

The trick is to access the `Array(UInt32)`'s internal buffer as a `Pointer(UInt8)` then make it a `Slice(UInt8)`, which can be achieved with some unsafe code:

```ruby
array = [1_u32, 2_u32, 3_u32, 4_u32]

File.open("out.bin", "w") do |f|
  ptr = (array.to_unsafe as UInt8*)
  f.write ptr.to_slice(array.size * sizeof(UInt32))
end
```

Be sure to never keep a reference to `ptr`, see [Array#to_unsafe](http://crystal-lang.org/api/Array.html#to_unsafe%3APointer%28T%29-instance-method) for details.